# My ImageView doesn´t appear on my Device screen

Tags: android, xamarin

I created a Layout and a Activity to that Layout.

In the Layout I only have an ImageView with a png image that is located in the Resources/Drawables.

When I launch the Application in my Device the ImageView doesn´t appear on the screen.

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px"
android:gravity="center"
android:visibility="visible"
tools:visibility="visible">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="350.0dp"
    android:layout_height="279.5dp"
    android:id="@+id/OpeningLogo"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:visibility="visible"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the Activity Code:

```
namespace *********
{
    [Activity(Label = "xxxxxxxxx", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/Logo")]
    public class OpeningActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Opening);

            Intent GoToLogin = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            this.Finish();
            StartActivity(GoToLogin);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want me to put something more tell me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you are blocking the UI thread of that Activity and it is never actually shown as intended. The UI thread does not get time to actually draw anything on the screen.

Instead you should do something like:

```
namespace GridSocios
{
    [Activity(Label = "xxxxxxxxx", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/Logo", NoHistory = true)]
    public class OpeningActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Opening);

            await Task.Delay(5000);

            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            StartActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Also notice the NoHistory = true flag is set. This means that you can't navigate back to this Activity after you have navigated away from it.

Comment: Thanks! Helped a lot. The NoHistory will help in the future too.